# Find the number of 5 digit numbers such that only odd digits occupy the odd places and repetition of digits is not allowed

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Odd numbers at odd places implies that number of possible combinations for odd places = 5 × 4 × 3 = 60
For the even places, it's supposed to be 9×7 =63 right?
So the possible 5 digit numbers should be 63×60= 3780. But it's not matching with the given answer

Comment: You can't repeat digits, so the even slots have fewer options than you suggest.

Comment: "*For the even places, it's supposed to be $9\times 7$ right?*"  See if you can explain why you used the number $9$ and why you used the number $7$.  To emphasize, when choosing the digits to use in each position we *do not* need to strictly choose the digits in the order of "first digit" and *then* "second" *and then* "third"... we can choose them in the order "first, third, fifth, second, fourth"

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you, I get it now.

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos I've written the entire question. It doesn't specify which numbers are allowed in the even places so I assumed that both odd and even numbers are allowed. And solving with that in mind, the answer I got matched with the result

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos please delete those comments.  You are wrong for the reason that... as alluded to previously in mine and lulu's comments... *the list of options available for the even positioned digits must not include those digits selected for the odd positions previously*.  Again... pick the first digit, then pick the third, then the fifth.  These must all be odd for a total of $5\times 4\times 3$ ways to complete these three steps in sequence.  *Now after having done that...* we pick the second digit which has $7$ remaining options and finally pick the fourth digit with $6$ options.

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos The total here is then $5\times 4\times 3\times 7\times 6 = 60\times 42$.  This is not $60\times 63$ and it is not $60\times 90$ or any other wrong answer that you or the OP might have come up with.  From the comments, our initial hints were enough for the OP to complete the problem correctly on their own, getting the expected answer which matches the book's solutions.  Your attempts after the fact actively harm future readers of this post who may have read your comments and gotten (*rightfully*) confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The punchline here is that in ordering your sequence of events for purposes of rule of product (*multiplication principle*) you are not required to order them in the same order as the digits appear in the final number.  By ordering the steps as "*Pick the first digit*" and then "*Pick the third digit*" and then "*Pick the fifth digit*" before continuing with "*Pick the second digit*" and finally "*Pick the fourth digit*" we have effectively made it so that regardless of what selections were made in earlier steps the number of options in later steps remains unchanged (*as required to correctly use the rule of product*), something which would not have been the case if we had done things in the order of "pick first" and then "pick second" etc...

Noting that after having picked the first, third, and then fifth digits when we now move on to picking the second and fourth digits we see that there are only $7$ and $6$ options remaining respectively (*as opposed to 9 and 7 as your initial attempt had you believe*) giving a final answer of:

$$5\times 4\times 3\times 7\times 6$$

Comment: Exactly! For each of the 60 choices we have $2\binom{7}{2}$ choices i.e. 42 choices , Therefore the answer is 60x42=2520.

Comment: Having phrased it as $2\binom{7}{2}$ feels awkward compared to phrasing it as $7\times 6$ or $7\frac{2}{~}$

Comment: It is just the two possible orders by the number of permissible combinations!

Comment: Yes... I understand how you came to that expression and why it is correct.  I am just saying it feels unnatural to have phrased it that way given the way we have phrased everything else.